# Excel vlookup for alphanumeric lookup value

Tags: excel, vlookup, alphanumeric

I have two list with hundreds of rows. I would like to know which items of List 2 are in List 1.

List1 items:

```
ENSG00000004139
ENSG00000004846
ENSG00000005187
ENSG00000005471
ENSG00000005884
ENSG00000006283
```

List2 items:

```
ENSG00000003756
ENSG00000003987
ENSG00000003989
ENSG00000004059
ENSG00000004139
ENSG00000004399
ENSG00000004455
ENSG00000004468
```

In this case, only item ENSG00000004139 in List 2 is included in List 1. I have tried the vlookup formula but it is not working. Anyone knows how to make it work with alphanumeric look up values?

I have tried the `VLOOKUP` and also the `IF` function nesting `IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP))`. None of them have worked. 
Not working example: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F42,List1!A39:List1!A$2:A$1000,1,TRUE)), "Does NOT exist in List 1","Exists in List 1")`

Comment: Never had an issue with  with alphanumeric values- make sure to use false with it , not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a count formula instead

```
=IF(COUNTIF(List1!A$2:A$1000,F42)>0,"Exists in List 1","Does NOT exist in List 1")
```

or a match formula

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(F42,List1!A$2:A$1000,0))),"Exists in List 1","Does NOT exist in List 1")
```

Comment: As it is alphanumeric, the match one did the trick. Thanks so much!